# Proving that family of fractions is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Define a set $S=\lbrace{p}\div{2^n}|p\in \mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rbrace$. Prove that $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

**My attempt:** Given two real numbers $a<b$, suppose that there exists $s\in S$ such that $a<s<b$. Then, $2^na<p<2^nb$ for some $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. If there exists $n$ such that $2^n(b-a)>1$, then there exists $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying the inequality. Solving for $n$, we have $n>\log_2(\frac{1}{b-a})$ and by the Archimedean property, such $n$ must exist which completes the proof.

**I have two questions:**

$1)$ Is this proof correct?

$2)$ My class has not covered anything about functions yet, so I am reluctant to use $\log(x)$ in a proof. I would like to know if there is a simpler way to prove this.

Comment: You actually don't need to "solve for" $n$, simply applying the Archimedean property is enough to   assert such an $n$ exists, which is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:  Let $a<b.$ To show that $S \cap (a,b)\ne \emptyset$:

(1).  We have $2^{-n}<b-a$ for all sufficiently large $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ because if $m\in \Bbb Z^+$ with $m> (b-a)^{-1}$ then $m\leq n\in \Bbb Z^+ \implies 2^{-n}<n^{-1}\leq m^{-1}<b-a.$

(2). Let $[a]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $a.$  For $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $i_n = 2^n([a]-1)$ and $j_n=2^n([a]+1).$ We have $i_n2^{-n}<a<j_n2^{-n}.$

Let $k_n$ be the least $m\in \Bbb Z$ such that   $a<m2^{-n}.$ (We have, of course, $i_n< k_n\leq j_n.).$  Observe that $\frac {k_n-1}{2^n}\leq a<\frac {k_n}{2^n}.$

(3). By (1) let  $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ where $n$ is large enough that $2^{-n}<b-a.$ We have $$\frac {k_n}{2^n}-a\leq \frac  {k_n}{2^n}-\frac {k_n-1}{2_n}=2^{-n}<b-a$$ implying $\frac {k_n}{2^n}<b.$  We also have $a<\frac {k_n}{2^n}.$ So $a<\frac {k_n}{2^n}<b.$

Therefore  $\frac {k_n}{2^n}\in S\cap (a,b).$

Comment: Note that in (2), regarding $i_n$ and $j_n$, it suffices to exhibit  some $i,j \in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $i2^{-n}<a<j2^{-n}.$

Comment: In my  previous comment to my answer, that should have been $\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 2):

The spirit of your proof is correct.

The following statement:

((Given two real numbers $a<b$, suppose that there exists s∈S such that $a<s<b.$))

implies the existence of $s$ before proving anything.

You are starting from the end and coming back to the beginning.

If you start at :((  There exists n such that $2^n(b−a)>1$ ))

Please redo your proof  using the same ideas but in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

Much more than this is true.

The $2^n$ is a MacGuffin:
"an object, event, or character  that serves to set and keep the plot in motion despite usually lacking intrinsic importance."
It could just as well be $n!$ or $n^{n^n}$.

In this case,
let $Q$ be an
infinite set of positive integers.
Then
$S=\{\frac{p}{q}|p\in \mathbb{Z},q\in Q\rbrace
$
is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

All that is needed is that,
for any $n > 0$
there is a $m \in Q$
such that $m > n$.

What you want is that,
for and $r \in \mathbb{R}$
and
$\epsilon > 0$,
there is a
$p \in  \mathbb{Z}$
and
$q\in Q$
such that
$|\dfrac{p}{q}-r|
\lt \epsilon$.
This is
$|p - qr|
\lt \epsilon q
$.

By choosing
$q > \dfrac1{\epsilon}$
and then
$p = \lfloor qr \rfloor$,
we have
$|p - qr|
\le 1
\lt \epsilon q
$
so
$|\dfrac{p}{q}-r|
\lt \epsilon$.